# How input canvas text box and button box?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm studying canvas programming.

I'm try to make canvas draw through text array and input type text ..

How make this same photo ?

[image]

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5:Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:2px solid#c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var Text_array = new Array("과자","모래","호두");

for( i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   document.write(" " + Text_array[i]);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the code snippet and question look in kind of contradiction to each other... it may be you can clarify the question and to be more specific? Please, use JSFiddle for showing code-snippets.

Comment: SO is here to help with what you've tried but SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` writes text to the document. You need to write it to the canvas element. Canvas provides it's own methods for this: [`fillText`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp) and [`strokeText`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_stroketext.asp), so you'll need to use one of these.

You'll also need to call the javascript for when you want this to happen. In my code below I'm calling it from a click on a link, but it could equally be called from an onload event, a button click etc.  I'm also providing x and y coordinates for where I want the text written on the canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5:Canvas</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function writeCanvas() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    var Text_array = new Array("과자","모래","호두");

    for( i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        ctx.fillText(Text_array[i], 10, (i+1) * 50);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:2px solid#c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas><br>
<a href="javascript:writeCanvas();">Write</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. but if i were made, not this.

Comment: I'm want to made canvas side input textbox and right side button

Comment: and I'm want to show canvas "과자","모래","호두" ..   and if i write same text , text is delete.

Comment: You have everything you need to achieve that, you'll have to work out how to do it though :)